# Brakes not stopping my bike

Tags: road-bike, brakes, rim-brake

I am new to cycling. I just brought a new single speed fixie, Takara Sugiyama. It's for commuting (commute include hills). When I went down a hill, the rim brakes couldn't stop the bike at all. It was basically out of control and I had to force myself to stop the bike. I've heard of bedding in brakes on a new bike, but most articles seem to only talk about disc brakes.

I'm not sure why my brakes are so weak?

---

[image]

From [https://www.amazon.com/Takara-Sugiyama-Flat-Fixie-Bike/dp/B0061NVB80](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0061NVB80)

Comment: How high are your climbs?    Are you in single speed or fixed gear mode?  Are you dragging the brakes all the way down the climb and risking overheat, or are you pulsing the brakes?

Comment: Was it raining? Are the rims steel or aluminium? Water on steel rims is a lethal combination...

Comment: I was on single speed mode. Since the bike was going downhill quickly, I was pulsing the brakes. That didn't seem to slow down the speed whatsoever.

Comment: Probably poor quality brake pads.

Comment: Can you brake on a flat road with no hills? Are the brakes installed correctly at all? Even if the brakes are bad they should provide *some* braking.

Comment: Show us a video close up of what happens when you activate the brake. Show us the handlebars (as you slowly squeeze the brake lever, tell us when the brake pads first contact the wheel on both sides), the wheel end (show us what happens as you squeeze the lever all the way from "not squeezed" to "squeezed so hard you think your fingers will fall off", and show us what happens why you try to push the bike along while squeezing the brake levers hard. Squeeze one at a time

Comment: Chain lube on the rims/brake pads can also reduce braking efficiency, which would be another good reason to clean the rims and pads. Also something to watch out for if you lube the chain - make sure it doesn't drip on the rims. Other substances to make the bike shiny could do that, too. I bought a used bike on Craigslist once, and the person had put Armor All on the tires and rims to make them shiny, and that made the brakes basically not work at all. I sanded the pads down a bit and cleaned the rims with alcohol, and after several careful rides, they improved.

Answer (score 33):

Based on the specs on the Amazon page, its a low-end bike with cost-conscious components.

A quick google returns reviews like https://www.bikeride.com/takara-sugiyama/  that say things like "brakes are underpowered" suggests it is an endemic problem with this bike.

Some cheap/no-cost things you can try:

- Clean the brake pad's surface - pick out any fragments of metal especially, and remove grit.  There may be some valleys that help cleaning, clean them out too.  Two pads in each caliper for a total of 4.
- Scuff the pads - if the braking surface is glazed and hardened then it won't grip well.
- Align the brake pads properly with the rim.  They should not hang off the edge and must not contact the tyre, but higher on the rim will provide better leverage.
- Clean the rims.  It is possible there are contaminants from manufacturing, or road salt/grit on the surface.   Warm water with a little detergent helps, then rinse well with cold.
- Check the gaps - presuming the wheels are true, there should be minimal gap between the pads and the rim at all times, just enough to let the rim pass through without rubbing.  This is adjusted by altering the barrel ad the top of each caliper, and another one on the end of each brake lever.

Things to try that cost money:

- NEW BRAKE PADS is the single best thing you can to do improve brake performance.  I personally prefer Kool Stop, which are excellent.   Cheap brake pads are no good at all.
- Replace the levers with metal ones.  From the look of the photo, the levers are plastic, and will have flex.
- Replace the calipers - they appear to be stamped metal.  These would be fine on a child's bike, but not stopping an adult going down a hill at speed.
- Replace the rims - if they're slippery then a light scuff may help tooth the brake track, but ultimately you need more friction.

Another serious point is Method - if you're not using the front brake, then you're not braking efficiently.  The most braking you can get out of a bike is "as much front brake as possible until the rear wheel starts to slide"

If you're only using the rear brake, change your method.

If you are worried about going Over The Bars, learn to shift your weight backward when braking hard.  Lock your elbows, lower your head, and stick your butt back like you're mooning the rider behind you.  This lets you brake more and harder.

---

Smittay raises a good point.  You could spend much more on making this bike work better than it would cost to buy a bike with better components.

This trendy fixie can be on-sold to offset the cost of a better bike that is more-capable of hills, to someone who only wants to putter 300 metres down a flat road to a coffee shop.

Next time you buy a bike, get a test ride in before committing.  I suspect you bought this bike sight-unseen, which is always a gamble.

If you're truly committed to making this bike better, its going to cost money and you'll need to get your hands dirty.  If you feel uncomfortable with tools and expect a bike mechanic to do the work, then the cost equation blows out very quickly.

Comment: Was the rant about gears really necessary?

Comment: New kool stop pads would run only about $10/wheel and I suspect would make an enormous difference.

Comment: @ojs I think so - the point made was that for someone new to cycling, commuting with climbs on a fixie is perhaps a hard start.  It seems likely that this bike can't descend safely either as new, so the bike is not suitable for OP's needs.  I don't want to put OP off riding - the bike will likely do that itself.

Comment: @Armand yeah good brake pads are the single best upgrade, and worth trying.  The other cost items perhaps leave for now, being significantly more expensive.

Comment: In the product pictures on ama(teur)zon the front brake pads are clearly mounted upside down which is rather revealing on the quality of that BSO.

Comment: @Carel makes an important point. It is likely that the bike is not properly set up out of the box in a lot of ways, and there may be other parts (headset, bottom bracket, pedals) that need to be tightened or adjusted as well.

Comment: If water + detergent doesn't clean the rims, I've heard that rubbing alcohol is another effective solvent for the much of the potential rim contaminants. Plus it's a household item. Unless you ran out in the pandemic and haven't had it restocked...

Comment: I’d like to add that new quality brake pads (Swissstop, Koolstop) are only an upgrade if the existing pads are bad (which is very likely in this case). If you have new-ish Shimano or SRAM brakes chances are the stock brake pads are quite decent.

Comment: First thing I did on my cheap steel fixie/single: replace those brakes stamped out of tin foil with proper mid-reach Shimano brakes and koolstop salmon pads. That did cost 25% of the price of the bike but without the bike was 100% less useful.

Comment: @WeiwenNg rubbing alcohol is a good solvent, just make sure it is not hand sanitizer. That has stuff like glycerol to make it evaporate more slowly and it will leave a slippery residue.

Comment: I'd like to point out that there's a lot more to brake action than pads and a clean braking surface. For people with an otherwise good setup this will fix 99% of problems. In a cheap bike that's  poorly set up , you have the issues of bad levers, bad housing, bad cables, loose nuts, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Although Criggie's answer contains everything I would normally suggest, I want to address the "single speed fixie" thing.

The bike comes with a flip-flop hub. Depending on how you set it up, it is *either* fixed-gear, *or* singlespeed. It can't be both at once.

If you have the chain on the freewheel, then it's singlespeed, and you need to fix those brakes.

If you have the chain on the fixed cog, then it's fixed-gear, and ... well, you still need to fix those brakes. But you can also learn to control your speed with back-pressure, and to brake (if not very quickly) by skidding the back wheel.

Get some foot retention though - those pedals will wreck your calves and ankles if you lose your footing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a video that may give you some ideas on stopping on a fixie.

My apologies for some of the less helpful responses here. The blue tires do look cool in the photo.